# My shiny app doesn't render anything after I add a tabItem

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

My application was successfully deployed (https://gustavonucci.shinyapps.io/Corona/), but after trying to add one more tabItem, it doesn't render anything, neither locally, and don't return any error.
Below the abbreviate code, because the full code has 1000 lines and the Stack don't allow it:

The additional tab is "tabItem (" map ")", as a comment.

Thanks,
Gustavo

```
{read and manipulate datasets}

#Shiny
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Corona Vírus"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard Global", tabName = "global", icon = icon("globe")),
      menuItem("Brasil", tabName = "br", icon = icon("line-chart")),
      menuItem("Brasil (Por Estado)", tabName = "estado", icon = icon("line-chart")),
      menuItem("Brasil (Por Cidade) - Em breve", tabName = "cidade", icon = icon("line-chart")),
      menuItem("Por Continente", tabName = "cont", icon = icon("line-chart")),
      menuItem("Por País", tabName = "paises", icon = icon("line-chart")),
      menuItem("Mapas - Em breve", tabName = "map", icon = icon("map")),
      menuItem("Modelos Preditivos - Em breve", tabName = "pred", icon = icon("desktop"))

      )
    ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem("global",
        fluidRow(
          box(width = 12,
              footer = paste("Última atualização em:", att),
              status = "info",
              h2("COVID-19 Dashboard")
          )
        ),
        fluidRow(
          box(width = 12,
              title = "Números do Corona Vírus no Mundo:",
              solidHeader = TRUE,
              status = "primary",
              collapsible = TRUE,

              valueBoxOutput("TotalCasos", width = 3),
              valueBoxOutput("TotalMortes", width = 3),
              valueBoxOutput("PMaisCasos", width = 3),
              valueBoxOutput("PMaisMortes", width = 3)

          )
        ),
        fluidRow(
          box(width = 12,
              title = "Números do Corona Vírus Hoje:",
              solidHeader = TRUE,
              status = "primary",
              collapsible = TRUE,

              valueBoxOutput("NCasos", width = 3),
              valueBoxOutput("NMortes", width = 3),
              valueBoxOutput("MaisCasos", width = 3),
              valueBoxOutput("MaisMortos", width = 3)

          )
        ),

        fixedRow(
          tabBox(
            title = "Gráficos",
            id = "grafTab",
            tabPanel("Evolução", 
                     plotlyOutput("Evolucao")),
            tabPanel("Casos Globais", 
                     plotlyOutput("CasosGlobais")),
            tabPanel("Mortes Globais",
                     plotlyOutput("MortesGlobais")),
            tabPanel("Recuperados Globais",
                     plotlyOutput("RecGlobais"))
          ),
          tabBox(
            title = "Ranking",
            id = "rankingtab",
            tabPanel("Global",
                     DTOutput("tabGlobal")
                     ),
            tabPanel("Brasil",
                     DTOutput("tabBrasil")
            )
          )
        )
      ),

{other tab itens}



      #tabItem("map",
       #       tabBox(
        #        title = "Mapas",
         #       id = "mapGraf", 
          #      width = 12,
                #height = 650,
           #     tabPanel("Mundo", 
            #             plotlyOutput("Evolucao")
             #   ),
              #  tabPanel("Brasil (Por Estado)"
               #          #plotlyOutput("CasosGlobais")),
              #  ),
              #  tabPanel("Brasil (Por Cidade)",
              #           "Em Breve")
              #),

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    BR %>%
      filter(Status %in% input$Status) %>% 
      group_by(Data, Pais, Status) %>% 
      summarise(Núm = sum(Núm, na.rm = FALSE)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = Data, y = Núm, color = Status, pch = Status)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      geom_line() +
      ylab("Número") +
      labs(title = paste("Número de", if_else("Casos" %in% input$Status && "Mortes" %in% input$Status, "Casos e Mortes", if_else("Casos" %in% input$Status, "Casos", "Mortes")))) +
      ylim(0,10000) + 
      scale_x_date(date_breaks = "3 days") +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) -> pTY
    ggplotly(pTY, tooltip = c("Data", "Núm"), dynamicTicks = TRUE) %>%
      rangeslider() %>%
      layout(hovermode = "x", 
             legend = list(x = 0.1, y = 0.9), 
             yaxis = list(autorange = FALSE),
             annotations = list(x = 1, y = -0.35, 
                                text = paste("Atualizado em", att, "-", "Fonte: Ministério da Saúde"),
                                showarrow = F, xref='paper', yref='paper', xanchor='right', 
                                yanchor='auto', xshift=0, yshift=0, font=list(size=8, color="black"))
    )
  }) 

{other outputs}

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You need to have a menuItem with "map" as the ID.  It's easier if you can provide a full reproducible example versus chunks of code.

Comment: I'm using it, and I added some more code, but I can't show the full code because of the size.

Comment: Please follow here for steps to recreate a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What if you exclude the following element from the `tabItem` which is going to be inserted: `tabPanel("Brasil (Por Cidade)", "Em Breve")` ?   "Em Breve" does not seem to be the right UI element

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem, I forgot to put `h1()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following block `tabPanel("Brasil (Por Cidade)", "Em Breve")` in the new `tabItem`, which does not contain the correct UI element.

Comment: I've posted it again in order the answer could be accepted